# Creating signup process using a bootstrap theme

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a signup process, allowing a user to signup. I have an existing signup theme that I am using.

This is what I have in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'sendemail.apps.SendemailConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

and urls.py

from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('courses/', views.courses, name='courses'),
    path('course-details/', views.coursedetails, name='course-details'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('', LoginView.as_view())
```

and signup.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
.....
```

Comment: what is your problem ? please describe it. If you want to use bootstrap theme as signup then just need a view to handle the `POST` request from the form that's all

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started with user authentication is to use [Django-Allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can override the library's templates and use a bootstrap theme. Django-Allauth provides documentation on how to install, configure, and override templates.